# Settings in ASPxGridView Skins

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview, skins

Can you set settings in ASPxGridView skins?

For example:

```
<Settings ShowHeaderFilterBlankItems="false" ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" />
```

This would be very helpfull because all the grids that are using this style would have filter bar and filter row enabled by default.

If it is not possible, could you please explain me why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to specify the ASPxGridView's properties (for all ASPxGridView instances in the corresponding theme) within the skin file:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dx" Namespace="DevExpress.Data" Assembly="DevExpress.Data.vX.Y, Version=X.Y.Z.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dx" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.vX.Y, Version=X.Y.Z.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" %> 
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server">
    <Settings ShowHeaderFilterButton="true" ShowHeaderFilterBlankItems="false" ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

However, the skin file is  intended more for specifying a visual appearance (styles, images, etc).